# Unable to run Opencv GPU on 64bit windows 7

Tags: opencv, cuda, gpu, gpgpu, windows-7-x64

I am creating an application of opencv gpu in visual studio 2008.The application is win32 application and the operating system is Windows 7 64 Bit.The application is being build successfully but when I am trying to run the program the program is getting crashed.The error message shown is "The application is unable to start".

Please suggest me. I used the dependency walker and it seems that the application is trying to call 64 bit dll of windows.

How to get over with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Dependency Walker displays confusing information for a 32 bit app if you are running the 64 bit version of depends.exe. I don't think it really understands the WoW (Windows on Windows) system. Also, I think that any attempt to link to 64 bit libraries would be caught at compile time. Most likely, your app is just not finding all the required DLLs. The Event Viewer should have more information about what the error was. Go to Windows Logs | Application. Use the log filtering if it's hard to find the entries for your app.